# AJAX GMAIL API Call Authorization error

Tags: javascript, ajax, gmail-api

I'm new to the GMail API and am trying to make an AJAX call to retrieve mails.

My code is:

```
 $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (request)
       {
           request.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com");
       },
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
         //  this.setState({Emails: data});
         console.log("Mail thread"+data);
       }.bind(this),
     error: function(xhr, status, err) {
       console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
     }.bind(this)
   });
 },
```

The response is a 401 error. On examining the request, I find the following query parameter appended to the request URL getting sent:

```
&_=1470236511985
```

So the request URL appears like this.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&_=1470236511985
```

Is the appended query parameter causing the 401 error or am I using the authorization header incorrectly? How can I resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `Authorization`-header should only be used if you are using an access token, with the value `'Bearer ' + accessToken`. If you are using your app key, it should be enough to just use the query parameter `key` like you are doing.

Comment: Even removing the header and passing the API key as query parameter results in a 401.

Comment: Get a Gmail API access token from [the playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). Use that token in the query parameter `access_token` instead. Does that work?

Comment: @Tholle Working perfectly. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Great! I have never used the key in my Gmail applications, but getting a token from the playground for testing purposes works great. Maybe a Google pro can elaborate on the key later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing purposes, you can go to the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and get an access token with the Gmail API scopes. Just use this access token in a query parameter named `access_token`:

```
var accessToken = 'ya29...';

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?access_token=' + accessToken,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.messages);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to get an accesstoken for real usage?